# How to get file extension from uploaded image with no extension in filename

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm trying to get the  file extension of uploaded image with

`$ext = pathinfo($_FILES[$type]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

it's working fine for the filenames having extension in it e.g `image.png, pic.jpg etc` but when i remove .png/.jpg from the filename e.g `image, pic`, it returns nothing.

Any idea how can i get the extension to be exact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [exif_imagetype](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) function does exactly that.

Comment: Great, that did the job